# Downloaded excel file not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to download excel file to the location in local system but on opening the file, i am getting error:

> The file format or extension does not match.

Although the file at backend is of same extension but i am getting the error
PFB the code:

```
string ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+downloadedFileName);


downloadedFileName= "Myfile.xlsx"
```

Comment: Just to be sure: the file sizes do match? Can you open the file when copying from server by hand? I don't see a `Response.Write...`, can you paste the code?

Comment: i suppose you are not mentioning the file extension name. i.e. xlsx or .xls

Comment: @PatrickHofman: the file has been saved to local system. When i open by double click on it , then i am getting the error not in code. And the file on backend is fine.

Comment: You have to set `ContentType` : `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for `.xlsx.` and `application/vnd.ms-excel` for `.xls`.

Comment: @Taosique: i have set for .xlsx only

Comment: How do you *generate* that file? Maybe it's generated in different format?

Comment: the file was already present at another location and it accesible.

Answer (score 0):

It will save as details.xls

```
Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Buffer = true;
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Details.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you're not using `Response.TransmitFile()`. Your code should be:

```
string ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+downloadedFileName);
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath); // full path here
```

Comment: Thanks Taosique, but can you modify the code so that I can ask the user for location where file to be saved.

Comment: @Aquarius24: I think you are asking something client side. That is just how your browser decides to. Chrome and IE for example will save it in the Downloads folder. This is not controllable from the server.

Comment: Right. `Response.TransmitFile()` takes path to file **on server**.